# How to use method onNewIntent(Intent intent) inside a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, nfc

I'm trying to use NFC Hardware from my device. But, the problem is that when I register the Activity to receive the Intent:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
```

I receive the result in an Activity instead of a Fragment. Is there a way to handle this result inside a Fragment?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`onNewIntent` belongs to Activity so you cannot have it in your fragment. What you can do is pass the data to your fragment when it arrives in `onNewIntent` provided you have the reference to the fragment.

```
Fragment fragment;  
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    // Check if the fragment is an instance of the right fragment
    if (fragment instanceof MyNFCFragment) {
        MyNFCFragment my = (MyNFCFragment) fragment;
        // Pass intent or its data to the fragment's method
        my.processNFC(intent.getStringExtra());
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the lifecycle equivalent of `onNewIntent` in Fragment?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Fragments don't have launch modes, on top of that they aren't initiated by `Intent` as opposed to Activity, so there is no equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed my issue the following way:

in MyActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
}
```

in MyFragment.java

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (getActivity() != null && getActivity().getIntent().hasExtra(...)) {
        // do whatever needed
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `LiveData`:

Repository:

```
class IntentRepo  {
    private val _intent = MutableLiveData<Intent>()

    val get: LiveData<Intent> = Transformations.map(_intent) { it!! }

    fun set(intent: Intent) { _intent.value = intent }
}
```

Activity ViewModel:

```
class MainViewModel(intentRepo: IntentRepo) : ViewModel() {
    val intent = intentRepo
}
```

Activity

```
override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent)
    viewModel.intent.set(intent)
}
```

Fragment

```
viewModel.intent.get.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
    // Your intent: $it
})
```

Answer (score -1):

We handled the call in a more dynamic way to support any fragment, by having in the `Activity` something like:

```java
// ...

public class ActivityMain extends AppCompatActivity {

    // ...

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        Fragment fragment = getFragment();
        if (fragment != null) {
            try {
                Method method = fragment.getClass().getMethod("onNewIntent", Intent.class);
                method.invoke(fragment, intent);
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException ignored) {
            } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to call onNewIntent method for class: " + fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
            }
        }
    }

    public Fragment getFragment() {
        // For NAVIGATION-DRAWER only
        // (replace below logic, if you use View-Pager).

        FragmentManager manager = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.executePendingTransactions();
        return manager.findFragmentById(R.id.my_main_content);
    }
}
```

Then in each root `Fragment` simply listen:

```java
  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
  public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.i("MyTag", "onNewIntent: " + intent);
  }
```